# How to add links inside combobox?

Tags: java, swt

In the combobox dropdown, rather than just text content, how to add links as shown in this sample image:

[image: sample image]

Image shows edit & delete link in the dropdown along with the text content. How to implement something similar in Java using SWT?

Comment: The SWT  combo controls are text only and don't support this. You would have to write a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

In existing Combo available in SWT it is not possible to add links for specific function.
So the better solution is to create your own custom widgets in SWT.

**Writing Portable Widgets**
The SWT library provides two widget classes that are typically used as the basis for a custom 100% Java portable widget:

1. Canvas - to create basic widgets
2. Composite - to create compound widgets

Please refer [Write Your Own Widget](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) and
 [Developing custom widgets with SWT](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWTCustomWidget/article.html)  for creating custom widget.